# C# File Disappeared after FileInfo.MoveTo with Local Path (Windows)

Tags: c#, fileinfo

I Ran FileInfo.MoveTo("filename.txt") with just a name instead of passing a full path and the file just disappeared. I believe in linux this would make it go to the root directory "/", but on Windows I'm not sure if there is a such thing as a root directory beyond just C: Is there any way to locate my lost file?

Comment: Both window and LINUX will look for the file by default in the folder where the c# exe is located.

Comment: *file just disappeared* - more likely it went into the current/working directory, whatever the current directory was at the time of the move, probably the location of the exe but it can be changed. Search the exe folder, look in the "start in" you see in properties of the exe, or last resort search the whole hard disk..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be in project folder. Usually files without specefying path are saved there. (in folder with .exe file)

Comment: The exe doesn't go in the project folder (the folder where the csproj is)

Comment: @caiusJard i meant the debug/release folder
source\repos\Project_name\bin\Debug
and there should it be.

Answer (score 3):

It is likely in the working folder that your executable is running from. For example, MyApp\bin\Debug, depending on the configuration you are running in.

Comment: Yup! its in the project folder, didn't even think of that. Thanks all!